# How to just retrieve the integer of a aggregate query in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

This might be a really dumb question, but how do I just retrieve the Integer using the query below?

```
staravg = UserReview.objects.filter(name__username__iexact=username).aggregate(Avg('stars'))
```

If I do {{ staravg }} in my template, I get {'stars__avg': 3.3333333333333335}.  I am aware I could just retrieve the 3.333 with a template filter of some sort, but there has to be a more simple way to just retrieve the Integer right?  stars is from an IntegerField FYI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because [`aggregate()` returns a dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset):

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked,
>   returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. The name is an identifier
>   for the aggregate value; the value is the computed aggregate. The name
>   is automatically generated from the name of the field and the
>   aggregate function.

The key of this dictionary is automatically generated from the field(s) you aggregate by.

One option would be to get the number from the dictionary in the view:

```
staravg = UserReview.objects.filter(name__username__iexact=username).aggregate(Avg('stars'))['stars__avg']
```

Or, you can set the key name manually:

```
staravg = UserReview.objects.filter(name__username__iexact=username).aggregate(stars=Avg('stars'))['stars']
```

Or, if you want to get it in the template, use a ["dot notation"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) to get the value of a dictionary item:

```
{{ staravg.stars__avg }}
```

You may also need to apply [`floatformat` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) to round a number to the X decimal places:

```
{{ staravg.stars__avg|floatformat:3 }}
```

Comment: Cool, I did not know about the floatformat, I ended up writing my own template filter.

Answer (score 3):

The queryset returns a dictionary. You need to convert it to a decimal:

```
 qs = UserReview.objects.filter(....
 staravg = qs['stars__avg']
```